# Unwanted Google permission automatically added (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, permissions, google-plus, google-signin

**UPDATE**: Our game is built with Unity and we are using the Google Play Game Services plugin by Google, version 0.9.35. We are also using Version 4.0.0 of the Google SignIn SDK, integrated manually, *without* Cocoapods.

We have integrated Google Sign In in our game and we'd like to request **only the basic account info**, but for some reason **the permissions asked also include  Google+ and Google Play**.

The following info refers to the iOS build (but we're having the same issue on Android):

We are not explicitly adding any scopes, and we are using an empty configuration/builder. When printing out the scopes as soon as the app launches, we can see that they are empty:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"Scopes: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes);
    // prints: Scopes: ()
}
```

Nevertheless, it seems that when the `signInWillDispatch:signIn:error` method is called, there is an extra scope added:

```
- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@"Scopes: %@", signIn.scopes);
      // Prints: Scopes: ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games")
}
```

I cannot find any references of this string anywhere in the project (neither the source Unity project or the resulting XCode project). I can see this scope in [the Google Scopes page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), but the page doesn't give any helpful information.

How can it be added automatically?

Probably unrelated, but the game features leaderboards and achievements on Google Play Services.

By the way, I tried setting `signIn.scopes = [NSArray array];` in `signInWillDispatch:signIn:error`, but it has no effect on the permissions asked.

The screenshot shows the permissions that are shown to our users, compared to the desired permissions (those currently used by Pokemon Go).[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what version of Google Signin SDK are you using right now?

Comment: I am using version 4.0.0

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but how did you initialize GIDSignIn instance?

Comment: Well, a lot has changed during the past few days. I made more tests, including building the XCode project given inside the Google SignIn SDK zip. It works fine, requesting only the basic user information.

Therefore, I concluded that the GPGS Unity plugin does something at some point, which makes it request more scopes, but I couldn't find any such reference in the code.

I decided to create my own plugin that simply wraps the iOS SignIn SDK, and it worked great.